# Make a nested entity attribute read only in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data

I have Spring Boot v1.3.1 application using mongo. And the following entities ( groovy ) :

```
class SchoolTrip {
    @Id
    long id
    String tripData
    List<Participant> participants
}

class Participant {
    Student student
    String metadata

    @ReadOnlyProperty
    boolean outdated
}

class Student { 
   @Id
   long id
   String name
   String age
}
```

Now when we save SchoolTrip object it should ignore the 'outdated' attribute of the participants but it seems not to work for nested objects. I can always read the current state of the object in the DB and overwrite the 'outdated' attributes of the incomming object but that solution is clumzy. Is there a clean and neat way to acheave this in spring?

Comment: What do you mean by ignore? You want the attribute to be loaded by the ORM but not to have it written in the DB?

Comment: Exactly. @ReadOnlyProperty is supposed to do exactly that, but it works only if I add it to SchoolTrip attributes and not in the nested Participant object.

Comment: You miss some things here. Please, update your entities with the annotations you're using for the attributes. How are you retrieving the participant List?

Comment: No annotations needed as I don't want refs or anything the participant list comes from the frontend requests and each participant has a full blown copy of an existing student. E.e json save request for SchoolTrip: 

 {
  "tripData" : "long trip",
  "participants" : [
   {
    "metadata" : "some data",
    "student" : {
     "id" : "123",
     "name" : "John",
     "age" : "23"
    },
    "outdated" : true
   },
   {
    "metadata" : "other data",
    "student" : {
     "id" : "234",
     "name" : "Galt",
     "age" : "32"
    },
    "outdated" : false
   }
  ]
 }